# What is a "direction prefix" in this context?

Tags: verbs, sumerian, prefixes

In [this book](https://www.ibs.it/images/9780099460251_0_536_0_75.jpg) there's a translation of a Sumerian word, namely *munintuma'a*, which is said to mean *"when he had made it suitable for her…"*.

Then this sketch follows:

```
┌─────────┐ ┌─────┐ ┌─────┐ ┌────┐ ┌──────────┐ ┌────┐ ┌──────┐ ┌──────┐
│   mu    ├─┤  n  ├─┤  i  ├─┤ n  ├─┤   tum    ├─┤    ├─┤  a   ├─┤  'a  │
├─────────┤ ├─────┤ ├─────┤ ├────┤ ├──────────┤ ├────┤ ├──────┤ ├──────┤
│direction│ │     │ │     │ │    │ │   made   │ │    │ │      │ │      │
│         │ │ her │ │ for │ │ he │ │          │ │ it │ │ that │ │ upon │
│ prefix  │ │     │ │     │ │    │ │ suitable │ │    │ │      │ │      │
└─────────┘ └─────┘ └─────┘ └────┘ └──────────┘ └────┘ └──────┘ └──────┘
```

where I don't understand what *direction prefix* is.

---

I suspect [this Sumerian verb coniugator](http://www.gilgamesh.ch/svc/svc.html?mu_vent=1&ni_loc=1&a_suf=1&diathesis=2&verbpattern=4&verbroot=51&verbrootx=tum__2&rl=svcex_d.js:ref_link_tum2&sub=1) could help me find the question, but unfortunately I just don't have the "tools" to understand not even the documentation of it. Hopefully somebody can leverage it to come up with a complete answer. I've tried switching the various checkboxes to get *munintuma'a* somewhere in the page, but the most I could get is *mi-ni-in-tum-ma* when checking *-mu-*, *-ni-*, and *-a-*, and choosing *tum₂* as the verb.

Comment: Perhaps compare the English suffix _-wards_: '_-wards_ is a suffix that forms adverbs showing direction ... [as in] forwards / eastwards  / upwards' [[Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/english-usage/what-is-the-difference-between-ward-and-wards#:~:text=%2Dwards%20is%20a%20suffix%20that,or%20look%20towards%20the%20north.)] There is possibly no English counterpart, so the class (_direction prefix_) rather than the actual counterpart in English ('her' / 'for' / 'he' ...) is given here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I don't understand. What do you think is the role of _mu_ in the above sentence?

Comment: In going from the literal "her...for he" to "when he...for her," the order reverses. The prefix "mu" must serve to switch the direction. Though an unrelated language, Hebrew does use a prefix ("Et" = untranslated but serves as *to* or *at*) as a marker of a direct object. It's especially helpful when a language allows a free word order. So "Et man bit dog" shows it was the man bitten by the dog, and emphasizes the victim. Not really that far from using *it* as our placeholder: "It was the man who was bitten by the dog."

Comment: Sorry, Enlico, I can't do better than my first guess, at why 'direction prefix' is there. Asking for meanings of foreign words/affixes is of course off-topic on ELU (you could try 'Linguistics').

Comment: In many languages, concepts for time use spacial metaphors. "when" refers to a direction in time, so it uses a direction prefix. An analogy in English is something like "around 4pm".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Linguistics SE. A "direction prefix" is not something in English grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what Jagersma calls the *ventive marker*, indicating that the action is somehow oriented toward the speaker. This sometimes changes the meaning of the verb:

É-e ʔi-ba-ŊEN-∅
building-DIR VP-3N.DAT-go-3S.NOM
"He **went** to the temple"

É-e ʔi-**mu**-ba-ŊEN-∅
building-DIR VP-**VENT**-3N.DAT-go-3S.NOM
"He **came** to the temple"

Other times, it just indicates that the action happened *here*, or that it involved the speaker in some way. In inscriptions glorifying particular monarchs, for example, the *mu* appears on pretty much all verbs done by that king. Or, when a clause mentions the source or origin of something but not its destination, the verb usually has *mu* by convention.

Without knowing more context, I'm not sure why the *mu* is here. But if you want to know more about it in general, it's covered in chapter 22 of [Jagersma's book](https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/handle/1887/16107).

Comment: In the book you linked, I read that _mu_, when applied to verbs of movement it means _in the direction of the speaker_; for instance, _ĝen_ means _go_, but with _mu_ it means _come_; so it's kind of a "switch" for movement verbs. Therefore the question becomes "what kind of property does _mu_ switch for verbs like _tum_?" (I assume _tum_ is not a movement verb.)

Comment: @Enlico Yep, that's the example above (ĝ and ŋ are two ways of writing the same sound). For non-movement verbs, though, the meaning isn't as clear-cut; it can indicate that the speaker is somehow involved in the action, or that the action happened here as opposed to somewhere else, or various other things. This is why it gets an entire chapter of the book—we still don't really understand what its core meaning is!